# Minor stakes bought at a premium & valuation for target company

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation

I would like to understand why when A buys 10% of B at a 50% premium then every B shares seems to rise by 50%. Isn't it a misleading induction ? (See today's market reaction of ALCLS FP).

I have edited my question according to your remarks. I am surprised with the down votes since I do think it's a legitimate question. Why should a minor stake in a company value it entirely ?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Do you have a 'quote' to share? Who is making these assumptions? As it stands, you are asking "why does anyone make any mistake interpreting cause and effect of any market action?"

Comment: what is ALCLS FP?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that I own 10% of a company, and yesterday my portion was valued at $1 Million, therefore the company is valued at $10 Million.

Today the company accepts an offer to sell 1% of the company for $500 Thousand: now my portion is worth $5 Million, and company is worth $50 Million.

The latest stock price sets the value of the company. If next week the news is all bad and the new investor sells their shares to somebody else for pennies on the dollar, the value of the company will drop accordingly.

Comment: But it may be that, for strategic purposes, the buying company needs this minor stake and is ready to buy it at a premium. Getting the minor stake could mean getting the essence of the target and, in my mind, may not signal the value for the entire target company.

Comment: When the next purchaser isn't willing to pay that same price, the value of the company will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, when a company purchases a minor stake, they often intend to increase the size of the stake over time. As a reference, note that Coca Cola has increased their stake in Green Mountain Coffee Roasters (GMCR) over time.

It also adds some "support" to the price because these investors may be willing to step in and purchase the stock if there is any distress or poor performance.

Finally, its generally a good "tell" that the stock has good things going for it and may be subject to additional interest from large investors.